# Testing iPhone view controllers: where to start?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

While developing an app I came to a point when I realized that I want to test my view controllers (and other objects as well) "outside" of the app. I've found a good blog post on [testing view controllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/03/10/testing-view-controllers/), however, sadly enough, I'm not familiar with any kind of software testing at all. So almost everything written there is a bit confusing.
I'm looking for a good place to start and here are my questions:

1. I suppose it would be more useful to read something general on testing. What would you recommend?
2. What about iOS specific info? Tutorials on *OCUnit* (which is now integrated in Xcode), *OCMock* (which was mentioned in that blog post), *UIAutomation*?
3. Will I be able to "run" a separate view controller like an independent app (to tap buttons, type in text fields, etc.) without explicitly making such app? What tool may I use for that purpose?
4. What is your personal approach to this?

Comment: Would love to hear more answers on this topic, especially for unit tests in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would greatly recommend this resource as it touches on most of the questions that you have:
 http://jojitsoriano.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/references-on-unit-testing-ui-automation-for-ios-applications/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, I guess this list is a little bit outdated now, but nevertheless I accept you answer. Thanks! And I've also found and [excellent resource on Objective-C TDD](http://qualitycoding.org/) maintained by @jon-reid, which covers testing view controllers as well.

Comment: It completely outdated articles. Most of that are using deprecated SenTest, another part of links is 404.